# Aggregate disk usage with Munin

Tags: munin, df

I want to aggregate a total disk usage in percent of all my nodes with Munin.

Actually I tryed :

```
[streaming;Disk-Space]
    update no
    contacts no
    disk.graph_title Total Disk usage in percent
    disk.graph_category disk
    disk.graph_vlabel %
    disk.graph_args --upper-limit 100 -l 0
    disk.graph_scale no

    disk.type COUNTER
    disk.label Total up disk
    disk.sum \
        str1.mynodes.com:df._dev_sda2 \
        str2.mynodes.com:df._dev_sda2
```

But display empty graphs.

Comment: Do you mean that if you have three volumes, respectively 30%, 40%, and 50% full, you want to display a graph that shows "120%", this being the sum of all three?  If so, *why*?  If not, what do you want to show, and *why*?

Comment: I want the disk usage of all nodes together as one entity.
If I have 3 nodes at 30%, 40% and 50% full it should display 40% (all 3 nodes have same disk size). I want this because my nodes are used for storage, I want to know how much % of total storage is still free to anticipate a new server order.

Comment: You want to calculate an unweighted mean, yes?

Comment: Yes, I want an unweighted mean.

Comment: This looks to me like a piece of plugin config that attempts to use the results of a different plugin to calculate a result; I don't think munin can do that. Do you know otherwise?  Or have I got the wrong end of the stick, and the code snippet you give above isn't intended to be used that way.  Can you clarify?

Comment: this is a code I made for the bandwidth aggregation of the same nodes that works fine. I Just tryed to play arround with df and the disks name to try to get some graphs without success. I used this page for some tips http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/HowToWritePlugins like percent graph_args, labels, etc.
As you said maybe a plugin need to be wrote as I did not found anything on disk aggregation on Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using cdef. Here's a working example that I did on my local server

```
[dhcp;av]
        update no
        ddf.update no
        ddf.graph_args --units=si --lower-limit 0 --upper-limit 100
        ddf.graph_title df average
        ddf.graph_vlabel percentage full
        ddf.graph_category disk
        ddf.av.draw AREA
        ddf.av.label average usage
        ddf.av.sum \
                dhcp;dhcp1:df._dev_mapper_rootvg_rootvol \
                dhcp;dhcp2:df._dev_mapper_rootvg_rootvol \
                dhcp;dhcp3:df._dev_mapper_rootvg_rootvol
        ddf.av.cdef av,3,/
```

I think for your setup it would be

```
[streaming;Disk-Space]
    update no
    contacts no
    disk.graph_title Total Disk usage in percent
    disk.graph_category disk
    disk.graph_vlabel %
    disk.graph_args --upper-limit 100 --lower-limit 0
    disk.graph_scale no
    disk.label Total up disk
    disk.av.sum \
        str1.mynodes.com:df._dev_sda2 \
        str2.mynodes.com:df._dev_sda2 
    disk.av.cdef av,2,/
```

You obviously need to change the number in the cdef expression to reflect the number of values you're adding together.